# What is the reason for the one-half in the normal pdf's gaussian (i.e. : why $\exp(-x^{2}/2)$ instead of $\exp(-x^{2})$ )

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It doesn't seem to relate to normalization, as the normalizing constant adapts to every possible "upstairs formulation", and in the standard case is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Does it relate to fundamental probabilistic assumptions or to useful functional properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for normalization, to ensure that the variance is $1$.

Comment: Ok, but I also noticed that for whichever value for $\sigma^{2}$, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}=1$$ , which may justify the one half, but not the variance

Comment: Certainly the integral is $1$. But in my answer I said the purpose of the $1/2$ is to make the variance $1$. Choosing $e^{-x^2}$ makes the variance equal to $1/2$.

Comment: In fact, you're right, as it only leaves a factor of $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ to control. I was confused at first as I am used to leaving it as $e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}$ with or without the normalizing constant. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. There are quite a few distributions for which a normalized version essentially tells the whole story. For example the general exponential with density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is just a scaled version of the normalized exponential with density function $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

and note that since the mean is zero by symmetry, you can calculate the variance quite simply. with parameter $a$ for the distribution, the variance is:
$$
v = \frac {I_a(x^2)}{I_a(1)} \\
$$
where 
$$
I_a(f(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) exp(-ax^2)dx
$$
a straightforward integration by parts gives:
$$
I_a(x^2) = \frac1{2a}I_a(1)
$$
so for $v=1$ we require $a=\frac12$